# getContext no aparece en la version de android studio 3.5 ¿Cuál seria el remplazo?

Tags: android, get

Estoy iniciándome en la programación android y me tope que el `getContext` no aparece en la versión `3.5` es por eso que pregunto

¿Cuál sería el remplazo? o ¿Cómo se utiliza?

desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1):

En realidad [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getContext()) existe en el SDK desde la versión 1 de la API.

Actualmente al crear un proyecto, las Activity extienden por default de `AppCompatActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

pero **la clase [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) no contiene el método [getContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getContext())** es por esa razón que "no aparece".

> ¿Cuál sería el remplazo? o ¿Cómo se utiliza?

Si te encuentras en una Activity , puedes usar `this` dentro del método

```
onCreate()
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    ...
    Context context = this;
    ...
    ...      
    }
```

puedes usar también `getApplicationContext()`

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

> [getApplicationContext()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getApplicationContext()): Devuelve el contexto del objeto de
>   aplicación global único del proceso actual. Por lo general, esto solo
>   debe usarse si necesita un contexto cuyo ciclo de vida esté separado
>   del contexto actual, que esté vinculado a la vida útil del proceso en
>   lugar del componente actual.

Si te encuentras en un `Fragment`, puedes usar como contexto la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, esto puedes realizarlo usando el método getActivity()

> [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) Devuelve la actividad a la que este fragmento está
>   asociado actualmente.

Comment: ok muchas gracias. voy a probar